# Set Tab Bar title programatically at Startup for 5 Tab Bar item, 4 of which is embedded in Navigation Controller, 1 is not. Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate, tabview

How to set the tab bar title at Startup or `AppDelegates`. I have 5 `Tab Bar Item`, 4 of which is embedded in a `Navigation Controller` and 1 is without and just a `tab bar item`. Please see the following pic

[image: Pic]

## Updated on the VC calling the method

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ProfileChgLang (){

    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
    NSString *sLanguage;
}

- (IBAction)btnChinese:(id)sender {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:@"CN" forKey:@"txtLanguage"];

    [(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate setupTabBar];

    //UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    //==== Is the following correct? ===== 
    UITabBarController * tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
    [self presentViewController:tabBarController animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
    //====================================
```

## Update on app delegate

```
 - (void)setupTabBar {
    //===Should be this 
    UITabBarController * tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)[self.window rootViewController];
    //===Or this 
    UITabBarController * tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];

    if(tabBarController != nil) {
        ((UIViewController*)[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]).tabBarItem.title = @"Your desired Title";
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any `UIViewController` have this property `tabBarItem` because is an extension of `UIViewController` so you only have to get your viewController and set his `tabBarItem.title` property = "your desiredTitle"

## UPDATE

**Objective-C Code**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self setupTabBar];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

- (void)setupTabBar {
    UITabBarController * tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)[self.window rootViewController];
    if(tabBarController != nil) {
        ((UIViewController*)[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3]).tabBarItem.title = @"YourDesiredTitle";
    }
}
```

**Swift Code**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        //Whatever you have here
        self.setupTabBar()

        return true
    }

func setupTabBar() {

    if let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
       if let navigationsControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers as? [UIViewController] {
   navigationsControllers[3].tabBarItem.title = "YourTitle"
       }
   }
}
```

## UPDATE #2

if you want to call this method from anywhere in your code you must

1. import your AppDelegate.h in the .m where you want to use it
2. add this method in your AppDelegate.h in order to make this method public
3. call this method like this:

**Code**

```
   [(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate setupTabBar];
```

[image]

Comment: If I set the title  at each view, I only get the title changed when i click on the tab bar item. I want it to change to the desire title at Load. This is because I want to switch my title between Chinese and English, please help.

Comment: @HansheungCheah you need to do this in your appDelegate in the finishLoad method, but if you want to simply translate your titles you can do it using NSLocalizedString or localizing your storyboard

Comment: My chinese title is a string no need to translate. How to do it at appDelegate?

Comment: Sorry, but i am coding in Objective C, can you help out?

Comment: @HansheungCheah check again and let me know

Comment: Wow you are an expert, it works even with different tab index. It is working. Thank you so much.

Comment: Your welcome @HansheungCheah happy coding and best regards

Comment: @Hi Reiner, I have another button that switch between Chinese and English, how to trigger setupTabBar?

Comment: Thanks Reiner, manage to call the method but the tabbar title remains the same? Is it because of this `(UITabBarController*)[self.window rootViewController];` I am calling from another `VC`.

Comment: @HansheungCheah check if your VC have self.tabBarController != nil then maybe you can access to it directly

Comment: My VC doesn't have self.tabBarController != nil, how to access it directly? I am calling the method at appdelegate like you suggested earlier. Method was called but nothing happened.

Comment: can you share how is called that method and how are you navigating to your problematic VC? @HansheungCheah

Comment: Oh ya the VC is being pushed by another button. It is embedded in a navigation controller. Give me a few mins I will update my question

Comment: @HansheungCheah you have that issue because you are instanciating another TabBarController if you want We can talk about this in chat

Comment: @HanzCheah please set title pragmatically on page load like `self.tabbaritem.title = @"tourtitle";`